# On realistic interpretations of quantum mechanics - single quantum systems and measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

I am interested in realistic interpretations (in the sense of "quantum state realism" or "wavefunction realism") of the behaviour of a single quantum system interacting with a macroscopic quantum system acting as a measuring device.

An example is a single photon, a beam splitter, two detectors and two devices that fire a projectile as soon as the detector registers a photon. The interesting question is: how does a realistic interpretation of quantum mechanics explain what is going on, in particular how do we get from a superposition of photon states (or superposition of photon + detectors + devices + bullets + environment) to a single bullet that we eventually observe?

From my point of view, the only interpretation that discusses this in detail and with a realistic - but bizarre - resolution is Everett's quantum mechanics, enriched with decoherence.

*Are there other interpretations?*

(I know de Broglie / Bohm, but that is not a viable approach to quantum field theory in my view; and I know Ghirardi-Rimini-Weber, which is a new theory, not an interpretation; I am not interested in interpretations that deny that this is a relevant question, or interpretations that deny that quantum mechanics can be applied to individual systems)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119687/discussion-on-question-by-toms-on-realistic-interpretations-of-quantum-mechanics).